# Using QGIS Graphical Modeler to join specific fields

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, fields-attributes, qgis-modeler

I wish to join one field from a shapefile to another shapefile within the QGIS graphical modeler. I am aware that there is a 'Join attributes table' algorithm but this joins all of the fields from the shapefile.

Outside of the graphical modeler, I can use the Joins process in the layer properties but I would much rather be able to use this function within my models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a **custom script** in the *Processing Toolbox* which you can then add to your modeler. To create one:

*Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script*

Then add the following code:

```
##Join_layers=name
##Target_layer=vector
##Join_layer=vector
##Target_field=Field Target_layer
##Join_field=Field Join_layer

from qgis.core import QgsVectorJoinInfo

layer_1 = processing.getObject(Target_layer) 
layer_2 = processing.getObject(Join_layer) 

field_1=Target_field
field_2=Join_field
joinObject = QgsVectorJoinInfo()
joinObject.joinLayerId = layer_2.id()
joinObject.joinFieldName = Join_field
joinObject.targetFieldName = Target_field
layer_1.addJoin(joinObject)
```

Make sure it is saved in `C:\Users\You\.qgis2\processing\scripts` for it to be available in the *Processing Toolbox* (you may need to close the script for the toolbox to update itself).

When you run the script, it should look like this:

[image: Join script]

where the user can choose the layers and fields to join. This has been tested in the QGIS modeler using QGIS 2.12.3-Lyon.