# Choose which MULTIPLE attributes should be joined -QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I need to select which MULTIPLE attributes to join in a QGIS model. It allows me to do this in the interface (Properties-->Join) but not in the QGIS Model version of Join by Attribute.

So I want the match to be by LOTPLAN and the then some attributes joined and others not.[image: Example in QGIS Desktop]

Join tool in modeler
[image]

Comment: You could try using the script posted in this question [How to use QGIS Graphical Modeller to join specific fields?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137611/how-to-use-qgis-graphical-modeller-to-join-specific-fields) which allows you to use the `Properties > Join` function in your modeler. You can add additional fields to the script.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph I don't want to join on multiple fields -I just want to be able to choose which fields should be included in the resultant table. So if for example Address is blank in the first table but filled in the second one it should populate it but not create another field called Address_2. You can do part of this in the desktop properties-join tool but not in the graphical modeler version.