# Join two shapefiles using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm searching how to join two layers using PyQGIS.

I found a few solutions on this forum, and I specifically tried to follow the solution given here :
[How to use QGIS Graphical Modeller to join specific fields?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137611/how-to-use-qgis-graphical-modeller-to-join-specific-fields)

The displayed interface which offers a choice in the target/join layer and target/join field is perfect !

This solution was given 7 years ago, many things have changed since.

Here the original code :

```
##Join_layers=name
##Target_layer=vector
##Join_layer=vector
##Target_field=Field Target_layer
##Join_field=Field Join_layer

from qgis.core import QgsVectorJoinInfo

layer_1 = processing.getObject(Target_layer) 
layer_2 = processing.getObject(Join_layer) 

field_1=Target_field
field_2=Join_field
joinObject = QgsVectorJoinInfo()
joinObject.joinLayerId = layer_2.id()
joinObject.joinFieldName = Join_field
joinObject.targetFieldName = Target_field
layer_1.addJoin(joinObject)
```

First I had an error on this : `QgsVectorJoinInfo`

Here: https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayerJoinInfo.html,
we can see it changed for `QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo`

So I tried replacing `QgsVectorJoinInfo` with `QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo`.

But now I have this error :

> "NameError: name 'processing' is not defined"
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptEditorDialog.py",
> line 228, in runAlgorithm
> exec(self.editor.text(), _locals)   File "", line 9, in  NameError: name 'processing' is not defined

Since I don't know what I'm doing, I'm not sure changing random thing as I find infomation on the internet will work.

I also checked this solution :
[Joining table field with shapefile using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133573/joining-table-field-with-shapefile-using-pyqgis)
and others sites like https://python-forum.io

I never worked with Python, I have literally no idea of how I can make it work.

This issue is old now; maybe I'm not supposed doing it that way?

I'm open to a better solution if you know how to automatically join 2 layers, without using the "add vector join" option in the layer's properties and without creating a new layer.

Modified code :

```
##Join_layers=name
##Target_layer=vector
##Join_layer=vector
##Target_field=Field Target_layer
##Join_field=Field Join_layer

from qgis import processing

layer_1 = processing.getObject(Target_layer) 
layer_2 = processing.getObject(Join_layer) 

field_1=Target_field
field_2=Join_field
joinObject = QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
joinObject.joinLayerId = layer_2.id()
joinObject.joinFieldName = Join_field
joinObject.targetFieldName = Target_field
layer_1.addJoin(joinObject)
```

The error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptEditorDialog.py", line 228, in runAlgorithm exec(self.editor.text(), _locals) File "", line 9, in  AttributeError: module 'qgis.processing' has no attribute 'getObject'

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/425202/edit) to include additional details.

Comment: Is that standalone code? Check this out: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279874/using-qgis-3-processing-algorithms-from-pyqgis-standalone-scripts-outside-of-gu/279937#279937

Comment: is there a reason to use python if that is not a language you know - may be looking at the `ogr` library in another language would be easier for you

Comment: For now, since I didn't find a way to make it work with Python, I used the Graphical modeler. It always exports a new output of the joined layers. Still from the Graphical modeler, I use "Network plugin" to update fields of the first layer from the output layer (using get_feature). There are always small files, so it is pretty fast. At the end, I have few layers that I manually delete. This is the best way I found to make it work, and that's not bad finally.